# Нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли выделять запятыми оборот "как отечественного так и импортного производства" и считается ли он несогласованным определением?

Однако в последние годы на российском рынке появились необслуживаемые ДРДГ (,) как отечественного, так и импортного производства(,) и выпускаемые российскими предприятиями шкафные установки на их основе, которые отвечают необходимым требованиям.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятые в указанных местах не нужны. Союз КАК..., ТАК И предполагает запятую только перед второй частью союза. Да, это несогласованное определение.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

Импортной (=ввозимой) бывает продукция; производство может быть "зарубежным".